# How to use a custom log appender in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

**tl;dr:** The [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-adapters) don't mention how to do that and there also don't seem to be config values to support that (see [All configuration options](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config)). Is there a way to have a custom log appender somehow?

For testing applications I like to evaluate log messages. For that to work you need implement your own log appender which stores the log messages in some data structure, then configure your logging backend to use this appender additionally if the application is run in the test context. For Logback it's just a class which `extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>` and adding that to `logback-test.xml` as additional appender.

Since Logback is not supported by Quarkus, I tried to create a custom log appender with `Log4j2` but had to find out that this also requires to add the dependency `log4j-core` because `log4j2-jboss-logmanager` does not contain the required classes and the docs say "Do not include any Log4j dependencies" (see [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#what-about-apache-log4j))

Maybe I have a general misunderstanding here? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: In my opinion a test shall assert that my production code logs with the correct level and message, so I simply verify that my code calls the Logger appropriately. There is no need to check that Quarkus logs stuff to a log file on disk etc., so I skip this part.

That said, you could simply use injection for the Logger in your production class (if you don't already do this) and then mock it in your test and verify that your code calls the correct method (e.g. Logger.info(...)) with the expected arguments (i.e. the message) on the mock.

Answer (score 1):

So this doesn't seem to be supported out of the box (see [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6133)). You have to write your own Quarkus extension as [this GitHub Anon](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6133#issuecomment-671819686) points out. And he actually did implement such a thing (see [here](https://github.com/hartimcwildfly/quarkus-custom-loghandler)). The problem with extensions is they not that easy to implement (see [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension#basic-version-of-the-sample-greeting-extension)) and they have to maintained.

Since the main point of the original question is to use logs just for testing, it's probably easier to have a workaround with the existing log handlers:

- Easiest solution is probably to use the file handler in the `%test` context, write your logs into the file and parse it to make assertions.
- Since the console log handler uses `System.out` by default (see [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.log.console-console-logging) & [here](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/7cf6c3e953a0f02a7676cc0f88529ec2d509ada4/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/ConsoleHandler.java#L37)) It should also be possible to overwrite it (it's just a `PrintStream`) with your own `OutputStream` which you can turn into a string after the tests ran through. But that's probably a bad solution since you won't have console output during the test run and might create other problems.